# download a file with curl, keep original filename and add timestamp or so one

Tags: windows, pdf, curl, download

i've started playing around with curl a few days ago. For any reason i couldn't figure out how to archive the following.

I would like to get the original filename with the output option

> -O -J

AND put there some kind of variable, like time stamp, source path or whatever. This would avoid the file overwriting issue and also make it easier for further work with it.

Here are a few specs about my setup

- Win7 x64
- curl 7.37.0
- Admin user
- just commandline no PHP or script or so one
- no scripting solutions please, need tihs command in a single line for Selenium automation

> C:>curl --retry 1 --cert c:\certificate.cer --URL https://blabla.com/pdf-file --user username:password --cookie-jar cookie.txt -v -O -J

I've played around with various things i found online like

> -o %(file %H:%s)
>
> -O -J/%date%
>
> -o $(%H) bla#1.pdf

but it always just print out the file as it is named link "%(file.pdf" or some other shitty names. I guess this is something pointing to escaping and quoting issues but cant find it right now.

**No** scripting solutions please, I need tihs command in a single line for Selenium automation.

Prefered output

> originalfilename_date_time_source.pdf

Let me know if you get a solution for this.

Comment: And Selenium can't call a `custom_curl` script when added in your path?

Comment: I think it could, but then the selenium script get's a new dependency(the script file) and also I couldn't build that parameter string that easy as it is currently with java